# Is there anyway to call function after nsDialog show?

Tags: nsis

I wonder if there is any way which I can call function after nsDialog::show.

My case is a custom page that need to run http get request after the nsDialog show.

```
    Function customPage
        nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $0

    ${NSD_CreateButton} 0 0 100% 12u Test
    Pop $BUTTON

    ${NSD_CreateText} 0 35 100% 12u hello
    Pop $EDIT

    ${NSD_CreateCheckbox} 0 -20 100% 8u Test
    Pop $CHECKBOX

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 40u 75% 40u "* Type `hello there` above.$\n* Click the button.$\n* Check the checkbox.$\n* Hit the Back button."
    Pop $0

    nsDialogs::Show
    Call MyFunc 
 FunctionEnd
```

Actually, the call for `MyFunc` is occuring only when im closing the nsDialog..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nsDialog running by solo thread, but actually you can use `nsDialogs::CreateTimer` to callback a function without specify time which.

You can read more about that on:

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html#ref-createtimer

Answer (score 2):

Use `nsDialogs::CreateTimer` with a short timeout and kill the timer in the function callback, it is a bit of a hack but seems to work fine.